# How to hide top bars for Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, publishing-site, publishing

I am creating a Public Facing Site(Publishing Portal) in Sharepoint 2016. I want to hide two top bars which are shown in the screenshot so that they are not displayed to the end user. How can I achieve that using Sharepoint Server 2016?


[image: Top Bars to be hidden for Public facing site.]

Answer (score 3):

To hide the ribbon as you highlighted for all users, try to add the below CSS in your master page.

```
#suiteBarTop, #s4-ribbonrow
{
  display: none;
}
```

For the only suiteBar that contains SharePoint word and colored black, try this

```
#suiteBarTop
{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way , apart from CSS to do this?

Comment: @PankajDalvi You could create a custom masterpage and remove the controls that correspond to the parts you don't want to display./

Comment: I can do that @Thriggle but what if my Administrator wants to Sign In and Edit the pages. In that case what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code into  tag in master page to achieve it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    if(_spPageContextInfo.userId==undefined){
        document.getElementById("suiteBar").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow").style.display = "none";
    }   
}
</script>
```

Or we can use Security Trimmed Control to achieve it, check the article below.

[Add a Security Trim snippet in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-add-a-security-trim-snippet-in-sharepoint)

Comment: Thanks for  the code snippet @LZ_MSFT. I think this should help.